# The set of all limits of the image of a divergent sequence under a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let $A=\{y=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n):$ for some sequence $x_n\to \infty\}$. My intuition says that $A$ must be a singleton. But I have been told that it must be a connected set (which is not a singleton). Please help me to understand.

Comment: If $f=\sin$, then $A=[-1,1]$.

Comment: Also, why can't a connected set be a singleton?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $A$ is indeed a singleton, but this limit needn't exist. Take, for example, $f=\sin$.

To show that $A$ must be connected, that is, an interval, you must show that $x<y<z$ and $x,z\in A$ implies that $y\in A$. Take a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\lim f(x_n)=x$, the same for $z$ and use continuity to show that, for big $n$, there must exist $y_n\in(x_n,z_n)$ such that $f(y_n)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is also a connected set, because you can see it as an interval. And intervals are connected in R (whith the normal metric)